# Wordpress wp_send_json_success() returns undefined on success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm new to Ajax queries in wordpress. I've got a jquery request in JS and a PHP handler that is running successfully and executing as it should. However, the response that is sent back using wp_send_json_success() is returning undefined and I can't work out why.

The javascript request:

```
    $('.iflo-visibility-option-item').on('click', function() {
        var post_id = $(this).attr( 'id' );
        console.log(post_id);   
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'iflo_update_post_visibility',
                post_id: post_id,
                visibility: 'Library',
                success: function ( response, status, XHR ) {
                    alert(status);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The PHP block in the handler that should return.

```
update_post_meta ( $post_id, $key, $_REQUEST ['visibility']);
$response = array('response' => 'Visibility was updated.',);
iflo_write_log($response);
wp_send_json_success( $response );
```

When the response is written to the log I get this:
`Array ( [response] => Visibility was updated. )`

The database update happens successfully. Any ideas why the response isn't getting to the client?

Comment: Maybe stop wrapping `success` into `data` …?

Comment: try : `success: function ( response) {
                    alert(response.response);
                }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is due to you putting the success function inside the data: attribute. Also, I do not see you declaring the Datatype. Try forming your ajax function like this:

```
     $.ajax({
        url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(form).serialize() + "&action=" + "validate_email_input",
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            //Before sending, like showing a loading animation
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
```

That should fix the undefined response.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated and I'm now getting a response. Also knocking my head against the wall for stupidity ;-)

Comment: It happens to everyone, I myself have mastered the art of banging my head against the wall for my own stupid mistakes :P